Arithmetic with big Oh
I encountered this in Ryan O'Donnell's book about boolean Fourier analysis, but it is primarily a question about manipulating equations with Big Oh notation.
They use the fact that $\cos(z) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}z^2 + O(z^4)$ to deduce that $\arccos(1 -2\delta) = 2\sqrt{\delta} + O(\delta^{3/2}).$
I understand where the expression for cosine comes from, using its Taylor series and the definition of Big Oh. However, I am not clear on the actual arithmetic steps they use to go from the cosine expression to the inverse expression.
It seems to me like they isolate the $1 - \frac{1}{2}z^2$ part, set it equal to $1 - 2\delta$, and then solve for $z$. This gives $z = 2\delta$, which it seems they then substitute into the expression for cosine to get $\cos(2\sqrt{\delta}) - O(\delta^2) = 1 - 2\sqrt{\delta}$. Then, it seems like the next step would be to take inverse cosine of both sides, but then what happens to that $O(\delta^2)$ part? I don't have experience manipulating these types of equations so I assume there are some formalities I'm neglecting here.
